Only Access ACME
I want to login via docker from testserver to own gitlab-server for pulling docker image from gitlab-server in testserver. The connection between testserver and gitlab-server is vpn, so I don’t need secure http from gitlab contrainer registery. Only http connection.
docker login --username xxx --password xxx ``http://dsgitlab-registry.directservices.local:5050
I got error messages
Error response from daemon: Get "``http://dsgitlab-registry.directservices.local:5050/v2/``": denied: 
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<title>ACME Access Only</title>
</head>
<body>ACME Access Only</body>
</html>

curl ``http://dsgitlab-registry.directservices.local:5050 is working.
Configuration
On self-managed instances, add the relevant configuration settings or changes.
gitlab-server
/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
git_data_dirs({
"default" => {
"path" => "/srv/gitlab"
}
})
.... email config....
registry_external_url '``http://dsgitlab-registry.directservices.local:5050``'
Testserver
/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"insecure-registries" : [ "dsgitlab-registry.directservices.local:5050" ]
}
Versions
Please select whether options apply, and add the version information.
Self-managed
GitLab.com SaaS
Versions
GitLab 16.9
I want to login via docker from testserver to gitlab container registry

You say that curl works, what does curl -i http://dsgitlab-registry.directservices.local:5050/v2/ output when run from the docker machine?

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 13 Jul 2024 12:08:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 87
Connection: keep-alive
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="http://dsgitlab.directservices.local/jwt/auth",service="container_registry"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}`

`curl -i http://dsgitlab.directservices.local/jwt/auth   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 13 Jul 2024 12:11:01 GMT
Content-Length: 101
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
ACME Access OnlyACME Access Onlyroot@h2969671:~# `
Your registry is misconfigured. It is setup to authenticate users on a URL that is not valid. You'll need to check the configuration of your registry, but quite possibly they may not allow authentication over http for security reasons.
